# Study Plan for Study Permit Canada

Tags: canada, student-visa

I have just received an email from CIC and they need me to provide them a study plan. I am not sure what kind of study plan they are looking for but here is what i got so far. Can someone kindly check for me and see if it is appropriate?

March 24, 2017

Canada Consulate

Singapore

Dear Sir/Madam,

I am Travis Jude Fernandez, 21 years old. I am now working as an English and Science Teacher at the Stairway To Hope Learning Centre.

Right after i finished high school and passed my SPM exam in year 20____,

I immediately set up my own business of a small stall selling drinks. But due to my lack of knowledge in managing the business, it was not doing well and sadly i have to close it. My mom who is the Project Manager of a school project under the "Association of Helping Underprivileged Children" (Persatuan Kabajikan Anak- Anak Miskin Sabah) that is the "Stairway To Hope Learning Centre" offered me to try to teach in that school while searching myself what i really want to be. My dream of being a successful entrepreneur is still in my mind. So  when my parents wanted to go and attend the pledge ceremony of my brother who passed the bar exam at New Brunswick, Canada,  i search online which school nearer to his place. I am the youngest in our family of 8 siblings. I am afraid to study abroad without my family members as i am very attached to my parents and siblings. So therefore i choose NBCC to be my school and with a short term three year diploma i will be able to go back to Malaysia to open my own business with the proper knowledge on how to start and invest on a business and manage it the right way. I also choose NBCC because i believe they have more advance teaching knowledge and technologies than in my home country and i also

want to open a business that will help my country to create job opportunities to those who are jobless.

Sir/Madam, I will really treasure this opportunity that you will give me to further my studies in your country. Thank you much and wishing you all the best.

Sincerely yours,

Travis Jude Fernandez

Comment: Study plan would normally mean the courses you would take and in what order you would take them and perhaps some interrelation. Kindly remove your personal details from the letter you posted. https://www.elon.edu/docs/e-web/academics/support/academicplan.pdf

Comment: @SheikPaul can you kindly elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 1):

By googling 'cic canada "study plan" ', I found study permit instructions for several Canadian embassies.

One description from the [Manila instructions](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5836E.pdf) was:

> A personal study plan: A description of your proposed program of
>   studies as it relates to your academic, technical, or vocational
>   background and future career goals.

Specifically for the [Singapore office](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM5850E.pdf):

> Study Plan: Submit a one page study plan which answers the following questions and includes any other information relevant to the processing of your application:
>
> - Why do you wish to study in Canada in the program for which you have been
>     accepted?
> - What is your overall educational goal?
> - Why are you not pursuing a similar program in your country of residence or
>     citizenship?
> - How will this program enhance your employment opportunities in your country of residence or citizenship?
> - What ties do you have to your country of residence or citizenship?
> - If it has been more than two years since you have left full-time education, please provide your C.V.
> - In the case of a minor applicant, what are your reasons for wishing to study in Canada? What is your parents or guardians immigration status in their current
>     country of residence?